# vbnet upload image hel

Tags: vb.net, image, upload

so i used to be able to do it but forgot how, as i had to start again, its the part

```
Dim bFile() As Byte = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(bmp)
```

that is the problem, im just needing to upload test.image or even bmp (my saved bitmap) or somehow upload an image from filestream, as i DONT want to save to computer disk...

```
        Dim clsRequest As System.Net.FtpWebRequest = _
DirectCast(System.Net.WebRequest.Create("ftp://ftp.myURL.info"), System.Net.FtpWebRequest)
        clsRequest.Credentials = New System.Net.NetworkCredential("myusername", "mypassword")
        clsRequest.Method = System.Net.WebRequestMethods.Ftp.UploadFile
        ' read in file...         
        Dim bFile() As Byte = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(bmp)
        ' upload file...         
        Dim clsStream As System.IO.Stream = _
        clsRequest.GetRequestStream()
        clsStream.Write(bFile, 0, bFile.Length)
        clsStream.Close()
        clsStream.Dispose()
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

try this:
insert the image:

```
Picturebox1.Image = New System.Drawing.Bitmap(New IO.MemoryStream(New System.Net.WebClient().DownloadData(UrlTOimg)))
```

upload the image:

```
Using ms As New System.IO.MemoryStream
    PictureBox1.Image.Save(ms, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png)
    Using wc As New System.Net.WebClient
        wc.UploadData("ftp://foo.com/bar/mumble.png", ms.ToArray())
    End Using
End Using
```

ftp url + password:

```
ftp://username:password@ftp.website.com/htdocs/ImageName.png
```

enjoy =)

Comment: im not wanting to download the image, im wanting to upload the image

Comment: used this before, i guess it works so ill try this out, Thanks :)